# how to set permissions for all only files and for anly folders in the publick_html?

Tags: command-line, permissions, putty

How I can run the command the command on the Putty for change the permisions?

I want to set permission for files should be `644` and permissions for folders should be `755` in the publick_html.

Please help me.

Comment: the folder name should be `public_html`, and the command should be `chmod 755 /var/www/public_html`, read the `chmod` manual: `man chmod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the full directory path is /var/www/public_html (probably not publick_html), this finds all directories (except hidden ones) under it and sets the permissions 755 for them:

```
find /var/www/public_html/* -type d -exec chmod 775 '{}' \;
```

To change permissions for all regular files (except hidden ones):

```
find /var/www/public_html/* -type f -exec chmod 644 '{}' \;
```

If you are not sure, what find might find, try putting echo before chmod, so the chmod commands only get shown, not actually run, e.g.:

```
find /var/www/public_html/* -type f -exec echo chmod 644 '{}' \;
```

If running a command gives you the error "Permission denied", prefix it with sudo, however being extra careful, e.g.:

```
sudo find /var/www/public_html/* -type d -exec chmod 775 '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks, my path is `/clickandbuilds/Genexjaipur/. I want to change permission for those files and folders.

Comment: I have tried with this `find clickandbuilds/Genexjaipur/ -type -f -print -exec chdmod 644 {} \;` and getting the `find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter` .

Comment: Just f... not -f